# Not able to set dictionary option in vim

Tags: vim

I'm trying to set dictionary option in gVim.

```
set dictionary += C:\mydict.txt
```

But it's not working. It's showing `error **E518 Unknown option: C:\myDict.txt**`

I've tried to put path in quotes as well, that is not working either.

Platform: Win 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try without the spaces around the operator:

```
set dictionary+=C:\mydict.txt
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. But that was a bit unexpected, white space is ignored in almost all languages.